# What does this piece of code do and mean?

Tags: python, pyopengl

I recently came across this python code...

```
array_type = (GL.GLfloat * len(vertexPositions))
final = array_type(*vertexPositions)
```

but i don't understand what `array_type(*vertesPositions)` is what it means and what it does... can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: perhaps see https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: `(GL.GLfloat * len(vertexPositions))(*vertexPositions)` creates and array of floats initializes with the content of the containers `vertexPositions`.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` python operator can sometimes be a bit confusing. It obviously can be used to make a simple product between objects that provide the appropriates magic methods, like `int`, `float`, `str` etc. e.g. `2*4` or `'Hi!'*3`. But the `*` operator can also be used to do what's called *decomposition*, it means it can be used to unpack the values of an iterable. Just to be clear – don't know if it means something to you – it is the python equivalent of javascript's `...` operator.

For example, the following will print `a-b-c`.

```
x = ['a','b','c']
print(*x, sep='-')
```

For more about the `*` operator i'd suggest you to read [this](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/)